# Oracle Control file issue exceeding column

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have control file with following option...

```
OPTIONS(DIRECT=TRUE,ROWS=100,BINDSIZE=209700000,readsize=209700000)
load data 
infile 'd:\test.DH' 
"str '\n'"
append
into table name
FIELDS TERMINATED by '!'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED by '"'
trailing nullcols
```

sample or records, the terminator is "!"

```
9334!376!15950!9109!0!29109!109!0!!10003!05.02.2015 03:51:27!05.02.2015 03:51:46!05.02.2015 03:51:27!0!0!0!S!00c08309ed178b3f!005683540!6829109!079015!0!0!!!0!F!299!!!0!0!!0!-1, 0, -1, 1423075906663, 0, 0, 0!{, 1, 24307, 3000-12-31 23:59:59, 0}!!{60200103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0}!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!=2, =0, =0, =0, =255, =829109, =510, , =1!1!00067!!!F,079015,,2993007,290009,5,02993007,005683540,6,6829109,,,,010006743081,0,10006743081,5,F,,,,290009,2079015,2079015,829109,93007,079015,2079015,829109,0,,0,07000,,,0,,,,,'00c08309ed178b3fH',,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,299,0,,a2040000005b6424,7205,36899550,
338!8376!11230!333777!0!33777!333777!0!!10003!05.02.2015 03:51:04!05.02.2015 03:51:14!05.02.2015 03:51:04!0!0!0!S!6d!004382577!3333777!3407582!0!0!!!0!F!299!!!0!0!!0!-1, 0, -1, 1423075874285, 0, 0, 0!{, 1, 24927, 3000-12-31 23:59:59, 0}!!{60200103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0}!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!=2, =0, =0, =0, =255, =33777, =600, , =1!10595!02020!!!F,3407582,,993001,20000,5,993001,004382577,6,3333777,,,,010595,0,0202010595,5,F,,,,220000,407582,407582,33777,993001,,407582,03407582,3333777,0,,0,5874000,,,0,,,,,'6dH',,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,299,0,_1281,a2820000005d213d,7205,36899550,
```

when I run this in I get exceed

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table name, column logs.
Field in data file exceeds maximum length
```

this field is the last column of the record... the column is 3000Byte... I know it' snot the issue of the length of the record as I tried importing the same file with [b]navicate [/b]and it loaded all without any issue... there something wrong with [b]str[/b]... and it try to load all data on column [b]logs[/b]

I tried 
"str '\t'"
"str '\r'"
"str '\n'"
 and none of them helped me... thanks for your time

thanks

Comment: What is the line `"str '\n'"` in the control file for? I haven't seen that in an SQL*Loader control file before. Thanks.

Comment: I read somewhere in forums they said it's for new line... not sure if it was that

Comment: Perhaps you could remove that line from the control file, run the load, and see it it works. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi thank... I did try that also no luck :(

Comment: @BobJarvis - that is the [stream record format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL984). Not sure if it's actually needed here though.

Comment: @AlexPoole - ah-ha! Thanks - I learn something new every day here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

thanks I found the issue, I had to mentioned number of character in control file infront of the field i.e

OPTIONS(DIRECT=TRUE,ROWS=100,BINDSIZE=209700000,readsize=209700000)
load data

```
infile 'd:\test.DH' 
"str '\n'"
append
into table name
FIELDS TERMINATED by '!'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED by '"'
trailing nullcols
    (log char(1500))
```

Thanks everyone for readying :D